# Line Notes for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, documentation

Does anyone know a tool, complement or a way to add notes in Visual Studio 2022?

as a

`//TODO:`

but showed as a pop up. like the

`Title="this is a note"` in HTML

but in my source code.

Other good example that explains what I'm looking for is like the notes on Word documents that can starts a discussion from that note and in that note.

I tried the same concept in VS code with this but didn't work

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tkrkt.linenote

also tried use the //TODO: **Task list** as way to achieve my goal but it is just insufficient....